# JSON response and use in Objective-C

Tags: php, objective-c, json

I am struggling to get my code to work. I have a PHP script which contains:

```
if($totalRows_Check > 0) {

    $level = $row_Check['level'];

    echo '{"success":1, "level:'. $level . '"}';

} else {
    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Username and/or password is invalid!."}';
}
```

In Xcode I have a call to the PHP script that returns "success" and "level". This is a part of the Objective-C code:

```
if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
{
    NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

    SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
    NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
    NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
    NSInteger level = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"level"] integerValue];

    NSLog(@"%d",success);
    NSLog(@"%d",level);

    if((success == 1) && (level >= 0))
    {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Using the debugger I can see the content of "success" and "level" which are what I am expecting.

2014-07-11 11:05:16.955 MyApp[1681:11f03] Response ==> {"success":1, "level:0"}

The issue I have is the if statement of:

```
if ((success == 1) && (level >= 0))
{
    // do something
}
```

My code is not passing the if statement: Can anyone see why and offer advice?

Comment: What `jsonData`, `success` and `level` return? Individually.

Comment: If you see these problems in the future, you can try running your JSON a through http://jsonlint.com to see if it identifies anything (which it would in this case.

Comment: Did you check what is the content of "success" and "level" ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid. The closing quote in `level` is in the wrong place. This would be brought into stark relief if you checked the success/failure of the JSON parsing routine, especially if you used the `error` parameter (as outlined by sumofighter666). You can also diagnose JSON issues by availing yourself of [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com).

To fix the invalid JSON, edit your PHP to move the closing quote for `level`:

```
echo '{"success":1, "level":' . $level . '}';
```

BTW, you can avoid these sorts of errors in the future by using associative arrays in the PHP code, and then use `json_encode` to build the JSON, rather than building it yourself manually. For example:

```
if ($totalRows_Check > 0) {
    $result['success']       = true;                 // use 1 or 0 if you really want, though I think boolean is more intuitive
    $result['level']         = $row_Check['level'];
} else {
    $result['success']       = false;
    $result['error_message'] = 'Username and/or password is invalid!';
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Hi Rob, well spooted. Many thanks for your ommenst concerning the associated array, i will take another look at that. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use errors. Easier to debug.

Do this way:

```
if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
        {
            NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

            SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
            // Use errors ! It will tell you what is wrong going on
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:&error];

            if(error) {
                 NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }

            NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
            NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
            NSInteger level = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"level"] integerValue];

            NSLog(@"%d",success);
            NSLog(@"%d",level);

            if((success == 1) && (level >= 0))
            {
            // do something
            } else {
            // do something else
            }
}
```

See what error tells you.